# Possible to factor this zero-crossing denominator sin(a+b) out of this zero-crossing numerator tan(a-b)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometric-integrals, rationalising-denominator

EDIT: This has been solved.

The reflection coefficient of light approaching glass with an incidence angle $\theta_i$ varies with $$f_R=\frac{\tan(\theta_i-\theta_r)}{\sin(\theta_i+\theta_r)}$$ where $\theta_i$ and $\theta_r$ are related by $$\sin(\theta_i)=n\sin(\theta_r)$$
where $n$ is the glass's index of refraction.

Plotting $f_R$ as a function of $\theta_i$ (and assuming say $n=2$) we get the following:

[image]

Clearly the expression has a well-defined limit at $\theta_i=0$ despite not being defined there due to the denominator. Is it possible to re-work the expression for $f_R$ so that it doesn't run into numerical problems near $\theta_i=0$?

EDIT:

I initially know $\cos(\theta_i)$ and from there use trigonometric identities to calculate the rest. I would like to avoid evaluating trigonometric functions (or their inverses), and therefore the expression shouldn't feature $\theta_i$ or $\theta_r$ except as terms within the argument to a trigonometric function.

Comment: In general it seems the limit will be $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$. I recommend a Maclaurin polynomial approximation to the numerator and to the denominator as functions of $\theta_i$. Alternatively (but more or less equivalently), find an acceptable way to compute the function $s(u) = \frac{\sin u}u$ near $u=0$ (and hence $t(u) = \frac{\tan u}u$ as well), and then rewrite $f_R = \dfrac{t(\theta_i-\theta_r)(1-\theta_r/\theta_i)}{s(\theta_i+\theta_r)(1+\theta_r/\theta_i)}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Great idea! But I had to amend my question: I currently avoid evaluating any trig functions (after knowing $\cos\theta_r$) and would like this to remain possible with the new expression. Therefore I can't have $\theta_i$ or $\theta_r$ in the expression except as terms in argument to trig function.

Comment: Why not add the full details to the post of what you have computed (and of which variable) and what operations you're trying to avoid, it would help in making an attack plan for an answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for the advice. This has been solved.